# Doctrine: Mapped key being inserted as NULL

Tags: doctrine, mapping, symfony

I have 2 tables, `cart` and `product_inventory` mapped by the column `sku`. `product_inventory` has `sku` as primary key instead of `id`.

Mapping is as follows:

```
AppBundle\Entity\Cart:
    type: entity
    table: cart
    repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\CartRepository
    manyToOne:
      variant:
        targetEntity: ProductInventory
        inversedBy: cart
        joinColumn:
          name: sku
          referencedColumnName: sku
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            nullable: false
            options:
                unsigned: true
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: IDENTITY
    fields:
        userId:
            type: integer
            nullable: false
            options:
                unsigned: false
            column: user_id
        sku:
            type: string
            nullable: false
            length: 10
            options:
                fixed: false
        quantity:
            type: tinyint
            nullable: false
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }

AppBundle\Entity\ProductInventory:
    type: entity
    table: product_inventory
    repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\ProductInventoryRepository
    manyToOne:
        product:
          targetEntity: Product
          inversedBy: inventory
          joinColumn:
              name: product_id
              referencedColumnName: id
    oneToMany:
        attribute_value:
          targetEntity: ProductAttributeValue
          mappedBy: inventory
          cascade: [persist]
        cart:
          targetEntity: Cart
          mappedBy: variant
    id:
        sku:
            type: string
            nullable: false
            length: 10
            options:
                fixed: false
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: IDENTITY
    fields:
        productId:
            type: integer
            nullable: false
            options:
                unsigned: true
            column: product_id
        quantityAvailable:
            type: tinyint
            nullable: false
            column: quantity_available
        quantitySold:
            type: smallint
            nullable: false
            options:
                unsigned: true
            column: quantity_sold
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

I'm trying to insert a record into the `cart` table but the mapped key `sku` is inserted as NULL. I've tried changing the primary key to the default value `id`, but it didn't work. I'm not able to figure out the issue.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping was not correct. It should have been the other way around. A cart can have many products (oneToMany) and there can be many products in a cart (manyToOne).

```
AppBundle\Entity\Cart:
    type: entity
    table: cart
    repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\CartRepository
    oneToMany:
        inventory:
          targetEntity: ProductInventory
          mappedBy: cart

AppBundle\Entity\ProductInventory:
    type: entity
    table: product_inventory
    repositoryClass: AppBundle\Repository\ProductInventoryRepository
    manyToOne:
      cart:
          targetEntity: Cart
          inversedBy: inventory
          joinColumn:
            name: sku
            referencedColumnName: sku
```

I thank you all for taking the time to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of the `sku` field is a string and your generator is defined to use IDENTITY generator strategy which depending if using mysql will be translated to `AUTO_INCREMENT`column attribute for the sku. Check the [doctrine reference](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifier-generation-strategies) for the strategies types.

Comment: It doesn't work even if I change the field type to integer and remove the generator strategy.

Comment: if you change the type to integer and remove the generator strategy you need to supply the value yourself, otherwise it will be null.

if you need an automatic value, leave the generator strategy in place with the id as integer.

Comment: It's not working. I need to map these entities only to fetch records joined by `sku`. If I remove the mapping, the values are inserted correctly into the `cart` table. Can you please elaborate on your answer by giving an example?

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time. I appreciate it :)